# Accessing hyperlink in SharePoint custom list using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 custom list and one of the columns in that is a **"Hyper Link or Picture"** field.

My requirement is, if the field URL contains year that is less than 2009, I need to set the Url to "#". As our business requirement needs all the records lesser than 2009 are considered for archieve, hence the hyper link needs to be removed.

[image]

How to read the URL for every hyper link and make it "#" if the hyper link contains 2008 using Javascript / JQuery? The custom list is added as a web part (Screenshot attached).

Your answer is well appreciated.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Have you tried SPServices in jQuery for SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in the right direction...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var fieldName = "LinkField";  // Put the name of the column here

$(function(){
   var index = $("table.ms-listviewtable")
      .find("tr.ms-viewheadertr")
      .find("table[DisplayName='"+ fieldName + "']")
      .closest("th").index();

   var rows = $("table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr:not('.ms-viewheadertr')");

   rows.each(function(){
      var link = $(this).children("td:nth-child("+ index +")").find("a");
      var href = link.attr("href")
      if (true){
         link.attr("href", "#");
      }
   });
});

</script>
```